# React-Testing-Library - taking a snapshot AFTER fireEvent

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm having trouble taking a snapshot after `fireEvent.focus()` is called.

Here's the test. I have two tests here, 1 that compares the snapshot before the input is focused and 1 that compares the snapshot after the input is focused.

```
describe("Unit: <OutlinedInput />", (): void => {

  describe("Initial render", (): void => {
    describe("renders as snapshot", (): void => {
      it("for standard fields", (): void => {
        const { asFragment } = render(<OutlinedInput {...standardProps} />, {});
        expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
      });
    });
  });

  describe("On focus in, no input", (): void => {
    describe("renders as snapshot", (): void => {
      it("for standard fields", (): void => {
        const { getByLabelText, container, asFragment } = render(
          <OutlinedInput {...standardProps} />,
          {}
        );
        const input = getByLabelText(standardProps.label);
        fireEvent.focus(input);
        waitForDomChange(container)
          .then(
            (): void => {
              expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
            }
          )
          .catch((error: Error): void => console.log(error.message));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

However when I check the snapshot, only 1 is created:

```
exports[`Unit: <OutlinedInput /> Initial render renders as snapshot for standard fields 1`] = `
<DocumentFragment>
  <div
    class="MuiFormControl-root MuiFormControl-marginDense MuiFormControl-fullWidth"
    data-testid="outlinedInputFormControl"
  >
    <label
      class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-marginDense MuiInputLabel-outlined"
      data-shrink="false"
      data-testid="outlinedInputLabel"
      for="name"
    >
      Name Label
    </label>
    <div
      class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-marginDense"
      data-testid="outlinedInputInput"
    >
      <fieldset
        aria-hidden="true"
        class="PrivateNotchedOutline-root-62 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline makeStyles-notchedOutline-6"
        style="padding-left: 8px;"
      >
        <legend
          class="PrivateNotchedOutline-legend-63"
          style="width: 0.01px;"
        >
          <span>
            ​
          </span>
        </legend>
      </fieldset>
      <input
        aria-invalid="false"
        class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputMarginDense MuiOutlinedInput-inputMarginDense"
        id="name"
        type="string"
        value=""
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</DocumentFragment>
`;
```

It seems that `asFragment` was created during the initial render of the component and doesn't get updated by `fireEvent.focus(input)`. This causes both snapshots to be identical and I guess React-Testing-Library only creates the 1 snapshot due to this.

What should happen is 2 snapshots are created. The one for the second test (that has `fireEvent.focus(input)`) should have different classes for various components. For example, the `<label>` element should have an additional class of `Mui-Focused`, which I can see is what happens when I run my app in the browser.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9):

I got it to work. Apparently, you're not meant to wait for the DOM to update before comparing the snapshot.

This is the change made:

```js
  describe("On focus in, no input", (): void => {
    describe("renders as snapshot", (): void => {
      it("for standard fields", (): void => {
        const { getByLabelText, asFragment } = render(
          <OutlinedInput {...standardProps} />,
          {}
        );
        const input = getByLabelText(standardProps.label);
        fireEvent.focus(input);
        expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: this is really cool :) I was looking for such a solution all day.